# how to get JSON data from login without alamofire

Tags: json, swift, xcode, nsurlsession

I am able login, but don't get any data from `listpeserta`. I want to get user's name etc

```
func onlinecheckin(){
    self.password.resignFirstResponder()
    let password1 = password.text;
    if let user1 = user.text {
        // To trim the characters to remove the empty space
        let username = user1.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        let passwordnya = password1!.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        //Send user data to server side
        let myUrl = URL(string: "https://url/jgcm/login.php")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "user=\(username) & password=\(passwordnya)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            print("response online checking =\(String(describing: response))")
            if error != nil {
                task.cancel() // To cancel uploading the task.
                self.AlertMessage("Error. Please press Login button again.");
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            if let datadownload = data {
                resultlogin = NSString(data: datadownload, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "");
                print("result of online checking:\(resultlogin)")
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                if resultlogin.contains("already") {
                    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menu")
                    self.present(secondViewController!,animated: true,completion: nil)
                } else {
                    self.AlertMessage("User atau Password Salah");
                }
            })
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let datapesertac = segue.destination as? datapeserta , let user = sender as? listpeserta{
        datapesertac.coba = user
    }
}
```

**data peserta controller**

```
var coba : listpeserta? 
namalogin.text = coba?.nama
```

it does not display anything, just show `nil`

Comment: `prepare(for:sender)` isn't called, right? Because you are not using the Segue VC in your Storyboard, you are presenting it yourself, instantiating it from Storyboard and present it. If `if resultlogin.contains("already")` is really called, instead do `perform(segue: "???", sender: self)`

Comment: sorry I don't understand, please give an example? @Larme